# Unable to find element with Xpath - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to click an Element but having some issues.
First, there's a pop up window which I'm switching to, which seems to be written ok.

```
foreach (string handle in _webdriver.WindowHandles)
{
     if (!handle.Equals(parentHandle))
     {
         _webdriver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
     }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to click an element inside this pop up by this code:

```
var myElement = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@id='firstname_d']/div[@class='ms-crm-Input-Container']/input[@id='firstname']")));
myElement.SendKeys("foo");
```

I'm getting an Error:

> Unable to find element with Xpath

The HTML is as follow:

```
<tr valign="top">
  <td class="ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign  FormSection_CellPadding ms-crm-Field-Recommended" id="firstname_c">
  <td id="firstname_d" style="overflow: hidden;" formxmlcolspan="1">
     <div class="ms-crm-Input-Container focus" id="firstname_container">
       <input tabindex="1010" class="ms-crm-Input ms-crm-Text" id="firstname" style="ime-mode: active;" type="text" maxlength="50" attrformat="text" attrpriv="7" attrname="firstname" req="1" value=""/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the id

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstname")).SendKeys("foo");
```

Or using contains

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, 'firstname')]")).SendKeys("foo");
```

> Edit

You can switch to the `<iframe>` after the window switch

```
foreach (string handle in _webdriver.WindowHandles)
{
    if (!handle.Equals(parentHandle))
    {
        _webdriver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
    }
}

_webdriver.SwitchTo().Frame("foo");

_webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("firstname")).SendKeys("foo");
```

Comment: Unfortunately , both are not working .it feels like I didn't success switching to the new window after all.

Comment: @YanivEliav Are you sure you need to switch window? try without it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it without the switching(BTW, I'm using Dynamic CRM Web software). I'm clicking on a button which opens a new window. seems like I'm unble to focus the new window.

Comment: @YanivEliav The `xpath` looks correct. Do you have more than two windows?

Comment: No. I have the "Main" window , and then the second one that pops up after clicking on a button in the "Main" screen. according to the HTML code it looks like a <form> inside this window.

Comment: @YanivEliav does it has `<frame>` or `<iframe>`?

Comment: Yes it does. it has Iframe. but both opened windows has the same Iframe. I have tried using the SwitchTo().Frame("foo"); but there are actually two opened windows has it.

Comment: @YanivEliav If you switch the window first there shouldn't be a problem, you switch the focus of the driver. I edited my answer with this.

Comment: 10x! Works like a charm(except it fills the data very slowly)

Comment: @YanivEliav You are welcome. The slowness might be caused by the connection or the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

u can write following code and try it 
                 Set st=driver.getWindowHandles();
                 Iterator it=   st.iterator();
                 String parent=t.next();
                 String child=it.next();
                 driver.switchTo().frame(child);
                     WebElement ele=  driver.findElement(By.id("id="firstname_container"));
ele.sendKeys("foo